# how can I do element.element in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qtp, hp-uft

Lets say there are multiple element `1`s, and multiple element `2`s on a page. Using a separate function for each element I have it return the unique `webelement`.

Let's say I want to find an element that is a child of element `2`. In `QTP` I could do this by:

```
.WebElement(Element1).WebElement(Element2).WebElement()
```

Is there a way to easily do this in selenium? I know I can do `findelement().findelement().findelement()` but I can't find a way to do `element1.element2.findelement()`

**Edit:** This might make it more clear

```
public WebElement testLoading(WebDriver driver){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='loading-test test-loadingTest']"));
}
```

Current Implementation:

```
for(WebElement e : Collection(driver)){
    e.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='loading-test test-loadingTest']"))
}
```

What I want:

```
e.findElement(testLoading(driver))
```

Comment: can you write more code?

Comment: Wonder if you have heard of XPATHS before.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my desired result by changing the way I structure my elements.

For example:

```
public By fooBar(AndroidDriver driver){
        return By.className("foo");
}

public boolean waitForElement(AndroidDriver driver, By element, int timeout){
    try{
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(element);
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException nseeContinue){
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

waitForElement(driver, fooBar(driver), 20);
```